# Enable SOAP schema-validation on client-side?

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, xsd, jax-ws, cxf

I'm calling a SOAP web-service from JEE6-client, like:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
...
Class<T> serviceClass;
...
Service service = Service.create(url, new QName(namespaceURI, serviceName));
T servicePort = (T) service.getPort(serviceClass);
```

How do I enable schema-validation on the **client-side** (before sending the SOAP-request to the server)?

Can I do this in java-code, or requires xml-config, etc?

**EDIT -** I also tried this modification:

```
boolean inbound = true;
boolean outbound = true;
T servicePort = (T) service.getPort(serviceClass, new SchemaValidationFeature(inbound, outbound));
```

but doesn't seem to have any effect... error is still thrown on the **server-side** if a mandatory value is missing.

I would like it to be caught on client-side and never reach the server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?) to enable schema validation for the client side you need to set `jaxws` property: `schema-validation-enabled` to `true`. Example XML configuration:

```
<jaxws:client name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

Or either java code equivalence:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("schema-validation-enabled", "true");
```